# Rings with rectangles with same perimeter but different surface

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory, integral-domain

Could someone find an example of a commutative unitary ring $(R,+,\cdot,0,1)$, that is *not* an integral domain, with an element $x\neq 1,0$ such that $$\{a+b\mid a\cdot b=x\,\wedge\,a,b\neq 1\}$$ is a singleton? Or there's not such a ring because of the request hides a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be the power set of $\{ 0, 1 \}$, with symmetric difference $\triangle$ and intersection $\cap$ as its addition and multiplication operations, respectively. This is a commutative, unitary ring, with $1_R=\{0,1\}$ and $0_R=\varnothing$. It is not an integral domain since, for instance, $\{ 0 \} \triangle \{ 0 \} = \varnothing$.

Letting $X = \{ 0 \}$, the set in question is
$$\{ A \triangle B \mid A \cap B = \{ 0 \} \ \text{and} \ A,B \ne \{ 0, 1 \} \}$$

But there are unique $A,B \in R$ with $A \cap B = \{ 0 \}$ and $A,B \ne \{ 0,1 \}$, namely $A=B=\{0\}$, and so the set in mind is the singleton $\{ \varnothing \}$, since $\{ 0 \} \triangle \{ 0 \} = \varnothing$.

Comment: +1 Translating to $F_2\times F_2$:  $x=(1,0)$ can only be achieved with $a=b=x$, and $a+b=0$.

Comment: Thank you, and what if I ask for a singleton different from $\{0\}$ ?

Comment: @Stan: I guess you could take $R = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $x=2$. Then the only solutions to $a \cdot b=2$ with $a,b \ne 1$ are $(a,b) = (2,3)$ and $(3,2)$, and both of these satisfy $a + b = 1$.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I've been inaccurate; that was pretty simple. What I meant was: what if I ask for a singleton different from the two interpretions of the only constants symbols of the language, that are 0 and 1? Is there an example of such a ring with $\{a+b\mid ab=x,\,a,b\neq 1\}=\{y\}$ with $y$ a "proper" element of the structure, in the sense of $y\neq 0,1$?